# make 1 dimensional array of strings with elements seperated by commas from 2 d array in numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, membership

I need to make a 1D numpy array from a 2D array, such that the elements within the 2 columns are joined and separated and the data type is a string.  I can do the opposite function with `np.split`, but `np.concatenate` does not seem to work the way I need it to, and there is no such `'join'` function like there is in pandas.

these are my arrays, which have the shape (53187L, 2L) and (27530L, 2L):

`dfSTcombined=np.vstack([txx_copy,dfSTA]).T
locatsCruSta=np.vstack([locatsID[:,3],locatsID[:,4]]).T`

problems ensue when I try to compare them for membership:

`dfSTinlocats=np.in1d(locatsCruSta, dfSTcombined)`
`dfSTinlocats.shape`
`->(55060L, 2L)`
this gives a length twice what I expected (55060L = 2*27530) because it is comparing each of the 2 columns in the arrays separately, but I need to compare both columns at the same time.

try another method:
`test4=np.where(dfSTcombined==locatsCruSta)`
`-> ValueError: shape mismatch: objects cannot be broadcast to a single shape`

so I need to create a new array with 1 column containing the strings from both columns, and a separator.

`[AR1006, 02]` (2 columns)
`[AR1024, 05]`

should become:

`['AR1006,02']` (1 column, though my notation my be incorrect)

The ultimate goal is to find membership of one group in another using something like `numpy.in1D` and then use the indices for that membership to select more data to match up 2 huge data sets.  I am not tied to numpy if it would be easier in pandas, but I don't know how to compare membership in pandas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mention Pandas as an option. I'd certainly choose this library because on top of everything else it has some very useful functions for manipulating strings (although I'm sure what you want is possible in NumPy too).

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> import numpy as np
```

Make your NumPy array into a Pandas DataFrame:

```
>>> arr = np.array([['AR1006', '02'], ['AR1007', '01'], ['AR1008', '03']])
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(arr, columns=['a', 'b'])
>>> df

        a   b
0  AR1006  02
1  AR1007  01
2  AR1008  03
```

Two columns can easily be concatenated, along with a separator, into a `pd.Series` object:

```
>>> series = df.a + ", " + df.b
>>> series

0    AR1006, 02
1    AR1007, 01
2    AR1008, 03
dtype: object
```

You could even turn Series back into a NumPy array with `np.array(series)` if you liked.

Checking for membership of series objects is also simple. In fact, you could use `np.in1d`:

```
>>> np.in1d(df.a, df.b)
array([False, False, False], dtype=bool)

>>> np.in1d(['02', '01'], df.b)
array([ True,  True], dtype=bool)
```

Comment: Perfect, this is what I needed.  My code is probably the least 'pythonic' it could ever be, but it gets the job done.  Thank you for such a quick response.

Comment: No problem at all! Glad the answer was of use to you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
>>> a
array([[0, 1],
       [2, 3],
       [4, 5],
       [6, 7],
       [8, 9]])
>>> b
array([[4, 5],
       [6, 7]])
```

Add an axis so that `a` can be broadcast onto `b` and test for equivalancy

```
>>> c = a == b[:, np.newaxis, :]
>>> c.shape
(2, 5, 2)
```

Use `np.all` along the last axis then `np.any` along the last axes of the result.

```
>>> c = np.all(c, axis = -1)
>>> np.any(c, axis = (-1))
array([ True,  True], dtype=bool)

>>> d
array([[4, 5],
       [9, 8]])
>>> e = a == d[:, np.newaxis, :]
>>> e = np.all(e, axis = -1)
>>> np.any(e, axis = (1,2))
array([ True, False], dtype=bool)
>>> 

>>> f
array([[ 2,  3],
       [ 8, 10]])
>>> g = a == f[:, np.newaxis, :]
>>> g = np.all(g, axis = -1)
>>> g = np.any(g, axis = -1)
>>> g
array([ True, False], dtype=bool)
>>>
```

**Try it a different way - with an explanation**:

```
>>> a
array([[0, 1],
       [2, 3],
       [4, 5],
       [6, 7],
       [8, 9]])
>>> f
array([[ 2,  3],
       [ 8, 10]])
```

- Add an axis to `a` (shape will be (5,1,2)) so that `f` and
  `a` are *broadcastable*.
- In the equivalency operation, each 1x2 array of `f`  will be
  compared with each 1x2 array of `a`.
- The comparision will take place *along* the third axis of the *new*
  `a`.

The result is a 5x2x2 boolean array (5x1x2 op 2,2 -> 5x2x2).

```
>>> g = a[:, np.newaxis, :] == f
>>> g.shape
(5, 2, 2)
```

- You are interested in any point where the 1x2 arrays are equal - along the third axis.
- To be equal, both *elements* need to be `True`.
- Using `np.all` along the third axis results is a 5x2 boolean array.
- The columns represent the comparision of the each 1x2 array of `f` with each 1x2 array of `a`.

The first column for `f[0] (array([2, 3]))` comaparisons and the second for `f[1]` comparisons.

```
>>> g.all(axis = -1)
array([[False, False],
       [ True, False],
       [False, False],
       [False, False],
       [False, False]], dtype=bool)
```

To determine if either 1x2 array of `f` was found in `a`,
use `np.any` along the first axis.

```
>>> np.any(g.all(axis = -1), axis = 0)
array([ True, False], dtype=bool)
```

To determine if any 1x2 array of `a` was equal to either 1x2 array of `f`,
use `np.any` along the second axis.

```
>>> np.any(g.all(axis = -1), axis = 1)
array([False,  True, False, False, False], dtype=bool)
>>> 
>>> np.any(g.all(axis = -1), axis = 1, keepdims = True)
array([[False],
       [ True],
       [False],
       [False],
       [False]], dtype=bool)
```

Finally `np.zero` or `np.where` can give you the index of the row(s) of `a`
where either 1x2 element of `f` were found --> row 1.

```
>>> np.nonzero(np.any(g.all(axis = -1), axis = 1))
(array([1]),)
>>>>>> np.nonzero(np.any(g.all(axis = -1), axis = 1, keepdims = True))
(array([1]), array([0]))
```

Broadcasting:

- https://github.com/dwf/rescued-scipy-wiki/blob/master/EricsBroadcastingDoc.rst
- http://scipy-lectures.github.io/intro/numpy/operations.html#broadcasting

Comment: I tried your code and it works in the example you give, however I am not sure what it is doing!  I need to think on this for a bit...

Comment: It took me quite a bit of playing around to understand how this works.  Pretty sure I saw this used on another SO answer.  I'll post links that were helpful to me as I find them.

Comment: Seems I didn't have it completely straight - see edit.

Comment: This last edit is as much for me as you (hopefully), it helps to try to articulate what you think you know.